# Select an Option from a menu

Tags: python-3.x

I apologise if this question has already been asked, but I've searched (on both the internet and stackflow) and couldn't find a solution to my issue. I have just started learning about python programming and am having a few issues. I have been trying to get the following algorithm into python code:

```
main ()
name = getPlayername
menuChoice = ‘’
get menuChoice ! = ‘Q’
    display menu
    if menuChoice = ‘p’ or ‘P’ 
        display Start Game message “Let’s play some golf!”
        playGame ()

    otherwise, if menuChoice = ‘i’ or ‘I’ 
        display instructions message 

    otherwise, if menuChoice = ‘Q’ or ‘q”
        display End message 

    Otherwise if menuChoice ≠ ‘P’ or ‘I’ or ‘Q’     
        display Invalid Selection message
```

Basically, I would like the player to type ether P, I or Q depending on what they want to do and follow up with the command (whether it is to display a message or continue onto another function). The following is the code that I currently have in Python:

```
def main (playersName):
getMenuChoice = input ("""
    Please select one of the following options:
    Play Game
    Instructions
    Quit
    """)
menuChoice = ['P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'I', 'i']
if menuChoice is p or P:
    print("Let's play some golf!")
elif menuChoice is i or I:
    print("This is a simple golf game in which each hole is 230m game away with par 5. You’re able to choose from 3 clubs, the Driver, Iron or Putter. The Driver will hit around 100m, the Iron around 30m and the Putter around 10m. The Putter is best used very close to the hole.")
elif menuChoice is Q or q:
    print ("Farewell and thank-you for playing" + str (playersName))
else:
    print ("Invalid Command")
    getMenuChoice = input ("""
            Please select one of the following options:
            Play Game
            Instructions
            Quit
            """)
```

However, when I run the code I always have issues with either; invalid syntax errors telling me that the = sign, or the : or the ' symbol is the issue and a statement saying that the 'P'in the "if menuChoice is p or P:" is not defined even though I have defined it in a list as a value of the menuChoice. After looking at different websites about loops and lists in python, all of my code seems correct but python doesn't think so. Can anyone help me with this because I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This might not do what you expect: `if menuChoice is p or P:` ;)
I suggest you to use: `if menuChoice.lower() == 'p'`

Comment: I tried that and it comes up with: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Sorry, i meant `getMenuChoice` instead of `menuChoice`

Comment: That worked thank you!

Comment: but now it's telling me that the 

    "else getMenuChoice.lower () != menuChoice:"

has an invalid syntax which apparently it's the 'e' in choice..

Comment: `else getMenuChoice.lower () != menuChoice:` should be `else:` you don't need a condition on the else case.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the condition and the issue went away but now when I enter 'Q' it just says invalid command instead of ending the "while menuChoice!= 'Q':" loop and printing the end game message. Even though I have indented all of my if statements underneath the while loop and not indented the print end passage (so it's inline with the while loop). I don't understand because shouldn't the while loop notice that the command entered is Q and end the loop?